# How can I remove the "<More" back header in my MoreController in a UITabView series of tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

The issue that I'm running into is that I have a container view pegged to the top of each of my view controllers. When I go to the **"more"** section on a UITTabBar view then it has a **"More"** header on each of the sections. I'm hoping to get rid of that since the bar is now "over" my container since it is constrained to the superview. It also takes up too much real estate to have the "more" and my container view one after the other. Looking just to get rid of the more view controller header.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to dig around and find and answer....

I created a class of UITabBarController and then added it to project

```
class newTabcont : UITabBarController{

    func initializeTabs(){
        customizableViewControllers = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeTabs()
    }

}
```

and I no longer have an issue....